# Load large computation sequence from file and evaluate matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, sequence

My problem involves large matrices (20GB+ in storage) where each matrix element consists of an algebraic expression. To bypass this size issue I wrote a script which converts the matrix into a computation sequence, and by doing so  more than halves the file size. Here is an example of how this is done:

Consider the arithmetic expression (a 1x1 matrix):

[image]

Running this through the sequencing code produces:

[image]

Where the definitions for the tx parameters are:

```
t1 = A^2, t2 = t1*A, t3 = t1^2, t4 = t3*t2, t7 = t3*t1, t8 = B^2, t14 = C^2, t16 = t3*A, t17 = t8*B, t23 = t8^2, t33 = A+B, t34 = t33^2, t35 = t34^2
```

For this isolated example it may seem pointless, but when applied to a 10,000 x 10,000 matrix the number of common sequences between elements reduces the storage size substantially (like a zipping procedure).

My question is how best to process these definitions which are saved in files using Python to rebuild the matrix and evaluate the elements.

For the small (1x1) example above this can be done easily:

```
from __future__ import division 

# Values for A,B,C
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3

# List of definitions
t1 = A**2
t2 = t1*A
t3 = t1**2
t4 = t3*t2
t7 = t3*t1
t8 = B**2
t14 = C**2
t16 = t3*A
t17 = t8*B
t23 = t8**2
t33 = A+B
t34 = t33**2
t35 = t34**2

# Print numerical result
print((1/2)*(6*B*C*t7+16*C*t16*t8+t1*t23*t8+B*t4+C*t4+t14*t7+31*t16*t17+6*t7*t8+16)/(t17*t14*C*t2*t35*t33))
```

Which gives the correct answer of `0.00565843621399`. For matrices which have larger lists of definitions I have imported the file which works well, but when the size of the file gets larger (1GB+) the import runs into memory issues when creating the `.pyc` file.

I can read the file line by line but this makes the evaluation of the matrix more complicated as the tx definitions are now all strings.

I feel there are multiple ways to approach this problem but I am unsure on the most efficient implementation for when the matrices get very large, so I am here asking more experienced people for some insights on how best to proceed with the problem.

Comment: You really need to be using Numpy and Scipy for this kind of thing.  I admit I haven't looked closely at what your exact problem is, but both Numpy and Scipy wrap BLAS/LAPACK linear algebra libraries which is what you need to be using for large linear algebra computations; not pure Python.